# Turning on IDENTITY_COLUMN ID

Tags: c#

Please how do I turn on  IDENTITY_COLUMN ID from OFF to ON. I've been having this challenge for 2 weeks now saying "cannot insert explicit value for identity in table 'ApplicantDetails' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

This is my code snippet
        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ////Calling Window Work experience page
            //WorkExperience frm = new WorkExperience();
            //frm.Show();

```
        /*string connectionString*/
        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" +
         "Initial Catalog=EmploymentDb;Integrated Security=true; User Instance=False";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ConnectionString, connection);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ApplicantDetails " +
       "(Id,Title, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, Address, Email, StateOfResidence, City, MobileNumber, DateOfBirth, HomePhoneNumber, YearOfGraduation, StateOfOrigin, LGA, NYSCCertificateNumber, SchoolAttended, NYSCStatus, Eligibility) VALUES " +
       "(@Id, @Title, @LastName, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @Gender, @Address, @Email, @StateOfResidence, @City, @MobileNumber, @DateOfBirth, @HomePhoneNumber, @YearOfGraduation, @StateOfOrigin, @LGA, @NYSCCertificateNumber, @SchoolAttended, @NYSCStatus, @Eligibility)";

                    //To INSERT and Retrieve records IN A db
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtID.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", comboBoxtTitle.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", txtMiddleName.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", comboBoxGender.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateOfResidence", comboBoxState.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", comboBoxCity.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", txtMobileNo.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", dateTimePickerDOB.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhoneNumber", txtHomePhone.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearOfGraduation", comboBoxYearOfGraduation.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateOfOrigin", comboBoxStateOfOrigin.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LGA", comboBoxLGA.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NYSCCertificateNumber", txtNYSCCertNumder.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolAttended", txtSchoolAttended.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NYSCStatus", comboBoxNYSCStatus.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eligibility", cbxAgeLimit.Text);


                    DataTable tb = new DataTable();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    //DataTable DT = ds.Tables["ApplicantDetails"];
                    da.Fill(tb);          //It's always pointing to this FILL table.    da.Fill(tb);



                    FillControls();
                    int affectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show(affectedRows + "Row inserted!");

                    btnNext.Enabled = true;

     try
     {
         connection.Open();
         int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (result > 0)
             MessageBox.Show("Successfully added!");
         else
             MessageBox.Show("Failed to add!");
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
    {
        connection.Close();
         }
   }
```

My SQL Query
 -- Try to insert an explicit ID value of 3;
-- should return a warning.
INSERT INTO dbo.ApplicantDetails (ID, LastName) VALUES
 '('Id,Title, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, Address, Email, StateOfResidence, City, MobileNumber, DateOfBirth, HomePhoneNumber, YearOfGraduation, StateOfOrigin, LGA, NYSCCertificateNumber, SchoolAttended, NYSCStatus, Eligibility')';
GO
-- SET IDENTITY_INSERT to ON.
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ApplicantDetails ON;
GO

Comment: do you have access / control of the Database table that you are trying to insert into..? if not get with and or hire a qualified `DBA` also if the ID is an Identity field, you cannot assign the value, the database after inserting will auto increment that ID value.. try commenting out the ID in your Insert and remove the ID from Insert as well as Values it should work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your `Id` column is defined as `IDENTITY` and you are including that column in your `INSERT` statement as below

```
INSERT INTO ApplicantDetails " + "(Id,Title, LastName, FirstName, ....
                                    ^.... this one
```

Remove that column from columns list and it should work fine

```
INSERT INTO ApplicantDetails " + "(Title, LastName, FirstName, ....
```

But if you really want to insert values to your `Id` column then I wonder why have you at all defined it as `IDENTITY`???

Comment: Thanks, but it's still complaining of this line;            da.Fill(tb);                      
 //String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: At least one of the values you are passing into the procedure exceeds the maximum length for the column that it corresponds to. You should set your text box maximum lengths to correspond to the maximum length of the corresponding database column, and/or truncate the value to the column maximum length when setting it as the parameter value.